# Swagger UI - Web API versioning when using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

We are using **Web API 2** on our project with **Swagger**. My problem is that when **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning** is applied as following:

[image]

the **Swagger UI** is ignoring the fact that now I have version in my API which needs to be provided.

I looked at several examples but none seem to address this issue in a satisfying manner.

How do I force Swagger to let me add the API version or just add the version number automatically to the URL?

**Swagger configuration so far:**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {

                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MoovShack.ServerApi");

                    // If your API has multiple versions, use "MultipleApiVersions" instead of "SingleApiVersion".
                    // In this case, you must provide a lambda that tells Swashbuckle which actions should be
                    // included in the docs for a given API version. Like "SingleApiVersion", each call to "Version"
                    // returns an "Info" builder so you can provide additional metadata per API version.
                    //
                    //c.MultipleApiVersions(
                    //    (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint(apiDesc, targetApiVersion),
                    //    (vc) =>
                    //    {
                    //        vc.Version("v2", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V2");
                    //        vc.Version("v1", "Swashbuckle Dummy API V1");
                    //    });

                    c.OperationFilter<MoovShackTokenHeaderParameter>();
                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {

                    // If your API has multiple versions and you've applied the MultipleApiVersions setting
                    // as described above, you can also enable a select box in the swagger-ui, that displays
                    // a discovery URL for each version. This provides a convenient way for users to browse documentation
                    // for different API versions.
                    //
                    //c.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();

                });
```

You can see that so far MultipleApiVersions are disabled - from one good reason as it doesn't produce any results. Especially since I am not sure what "**ResolveVersionSupportByRouteConstraint**" should do.

I also read that "**EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector**" has some kind of impact but I am also not sure if that applies to my case. When I enabled it, nothing happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use it like this in our project and swagger recognizes it and it looks fine

```
[ApiVersion( "1.0" )]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]  
public class SomeControlelr: Controller{
    [HttpGet("", Name = "Someaction"), MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction(string someParameter)
```

Comment: and when you are using swagger to test, do you have to put there the api version?

Comment: No, as the version is resolved depending on which version you choose from combo box. Follow this sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample